What happen if we eliminate only one point from a Cauchy complete metric space?
Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric. We know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is complete as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ (because is closed), and $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ is still complete. But if we take $[0,1]$, is complete as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ but $(0,1]$ (or if we eliminated any other point) is incomplete.
Let $X$ be a complete metric space and $x \in X$. Suppose that $Y = X \setminus \{x\} \neq \emptyset$. Under what conditions $Y$ is complete or not complete?
The obvious condition is that if for every $x \in X$ there exists a nonconstant sequence that converges to $x$, then $Y$ is not complete. This is equivalent to require that $X$ doesn't have isolated points.
Besides those two (equivalent) conditions, is there any other result that guarantee when $Y$ is complete or incomplete?
I didn't find information about this, I was solving another problem and this idea came to my mind.

A subspace of a complete metric space is complete if and only if it is closed. So, $X \setminus {x}$ is complete if and only if $X \setminus {x}$ is closed, which is true if and only if ${x}$ is open, i.e. $x$ is isolated.

@TheoBendit this works as an answer as well.

@TheoBendit thanks, but I forgot to write the condition that $X \setminus {x}$ is closed. Every result that I know is in the way ''$x$ isolated then $X \setminus {x}$ is complete''. I'm looking if there is a condition whitout requiring that $x$ is isolated. I know, if any hypothesis about $X$ implies $X \setminus {x}$ complete for some $x$, then $x$ is isolated. But the converse may not necessary true.

Well, I think that everything will be equivalent to ''$x$ is isolated''. I will try to formalize my idea

If $x$ is not isolated, then this means that there is a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to x$ and $x_n\neq x$. And therefore if $x$ is not isolated then $X\backslash\{x\}$ has no chance of being complete.
On the other hand if $x$ is isolated, then $X\backslash\{x\}$ is closed and thus complete, as every closed subspace of a complete space is complete.
All in all: $X\backslash\{x\}$ is complete if and only if $x$ is isolated.
